# how to match pattern contains parenthesis in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract all lines started with "Nancy(40)" using perl. Could anyone tell me how can I write the pattern match code for this. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the parentheses:

```
/^Nancy\(40\)/
```

This is how you match any characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: _"Starts with..."_ implies that an anchor is needed, i.e. `/^Nancy\(40\)/`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. I thought the only thing she was confused about was the parentheses.

Comment: You are probably right. I frequently read more into a question than what is specifically being asked. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively enclose the text with `if /\Q .. \E'`

```
if ( /^\QNancy(40)\E/ ) { ..... }
```

or use quotemeta

```
$reg = quotemeta ("Nancy(40)" );
if (/$reg/)  { ..... }
```

It is borederline in this case, but if the string was longer it would be clearer than using `\`